# How to map two expressions of differing types?

Tags: c#, linq

I'll start with some classes...

**The Domain Entity:**

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

**The View Model:**

```
public class AccountModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Bal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The Repository:**

My repository has a method on it that takes an expression and returns a list, like this:

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Account> Query(Expression<Func<Account, bool>> expression);
}
```

**The Problem**

My application generates an `Expression<Func<AccountModel, bool>>` in the UI. I need to somehow convert or map the **EXPRESSION** from `AccountModel` to `Account` so that I can use it in my `Query` method. I say "map" because, if you notice, my model and domain objects are similar, but don't necessarily have the same property names.

How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of filters do the expressions represent? Isn't it the case that the *implementation* of filtering shouldn't be the UI's concern?

Comment: I agree with @AakashM here, the UI should never make direct access like this. If anything it should be calling a service which can process, check and subsequently use the expressions. I assume you are doing some form of dynamic data access, hence the UI dealing in `Expression`s?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). Automapper allows you to map one class to another at one point in time and use this mapping configuration later on.

See the [Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection) page on the wiki for the kind of thing you are after.

**Update** As you are using Entity Framework, here is an update for remapping your expression from using `AccountModel` to `Account`.

In the [CompositionRoot](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your application, set up AutoMapper like so (ignore Code Contract statements if you do not use Code Contracts):

```
var accountModelMap = Mapper.CreateMap<AccountModel, Account>();

Contract.Assume(accountModelMap != null);
accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Id));
accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.Balance, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Bal));
accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.CustomerName, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Name));
```

This configures how the two data types relate to eachother.

Implement an `ExpressionVisitor` to use AutoMapper to rebind member access from one type to another.

```
/// <summary>
/// An <see cref="ExpressionVisitor"/> implementation which uses <see href="http://automapper.org">AutoMapper</see> to remap property access from elements of type <typeparamref name="TSource"/> to elements of type <typeparamref name="TDestination"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source element.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type of the destination element.</typeparam>
public class AutoMapVisitor<TSource, TDestination> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _newParameter;
    private readonly TypeMap _typeMap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="AutoMapVisitor{TSource, TDestination}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newParameter">The new <see cref="ParameterExpression"/> to access.</param>
    public AutoMapVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        Contract.Requires(newParameter != null);

        _newParameter = newParameter;
        Contract.Assume(_typeMap != null);
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic", Justification = "Required for code contracts.")]
    private void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_typeMap != null);
        Contract.Invariant(_newParameter != null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Visits the children of the <see cref="T:System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The modified expression, if it or any subexpression was modified; otherwise, returns the original expression.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="node">The expression to visit.</param>
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var propertyMaps = _typeMap.GetPropertyMaps();
        Contract.Assume(propertyMaps != null);

        // Find any mapping for this member
        var propertyMap = propertyMaps.SingleOrDefault(map => map.SourceMember == node.Member);
        if (propertyMap == null)
            return base.VisitMember(node);

        var destinationProperty = propertyMap.DestinationProperty;

        Contract.Assume(destinationProperty != null);
        var destinationMember = destinationProperty.MemberInfo;

        Contract.Assume(destinationMember != null);

        // Check the new member is a property too
        var property = destinationMember as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
            return base.VisitMember(node);

        // Access the new property
        var newPropertyAccess = Expression.Property(_newParameter, property);
        return base.VisitMember(newPropertyAccess);
    }
}
```

Then implement an extension method to make this easier to use:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class which contains extension methods for <see cref="Expression"/> and <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> instances.
/// </summary>
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remaps all property access from type <typeparamref name="TSource"/> to <typeparamref name="TDestination"/> in <paramref name="expression"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source element.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type of the destination element.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result from the lambda expression.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression">The <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> to remap the property access in.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> equivalent to <paramref name="expression"/>, but applying to elements of type <typeparamref name="TDestination"/> instead of <typeparamref name="TSource"/>.</returns>
    public static Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>> RemapForType<TSource, TDestination, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        Contract.Requires(expression != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>>>() != null);

        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TDestination));

        Contract.Assume(newParameter != null);
        var visitor = new AutoMapVisitor<TSource, TDestination>(newParameter);
        var remappedBody = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        if (remappedBody == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to remap expression");

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDestination, TResult>>(remappedBody, newParameter);
    }
}
```

This can subsequently be used like so (in an NUnit test):

```
[TestFixture]
public class RemappingTests
{
    #region Setup/Teardown
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up the variables before each test.
    /// </summary>
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var accountModelMap = Mapper.CreateMap<AccountModel, Account>();
        Contract.Assume(accountModelMap != null);
        accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Id));
        accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.Balance, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Bal));
        accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.CustomerName, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Name));
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        Mapper.Reset();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks that <see cref="ExpressionExtensions.RemapForType{TSource, TDestination, TResult}(Expression{Func{TSource, TResult}})"/> correctly remaps all property access for the new type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="balance">The balance to use as the value for <see cref="Account.Balance"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the <see cref="Account.Balance"/> was greater than 50.</returns>
    [TestCase(0, Result = false)]
    [TestCase(80, Result = true)]
    public bool RemapperUsesPropertiesOfNewDataType(double balance)
    {
        Expression<Func<AccountModel, bool>> modelExpr = model => model.Bal > 50;

        var accountExpr = modelExpr.RemapForType<AccountModel, Account, bool>();

        var compiled = accountExpr.Compile();
        Contract.Assume(compiled != null);

        var hasBalance = compiled(new Account {Balance = balance});

        return hasBalance;
    }
}
```

In case that is too much code to find the exact call, here it is:

```
Expression<Func<AccountModel, bool>> modelExpr = model => model.Bal > 50;
var accountExpr = modelExpr.RemapForType<AccountModel, Account, bool>();
```

Comment: This works fine if there is no type conversion made on the mappings (in the example: int to int, double to double and string to string). BUT if there is a map from int to int? (nullable int) like accountModelMap.ForMember(account => account.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Id.HasValue ? model.Id.Value : 0)) IT WON'T WORK. Any Idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ExpressionVisitor` to rewrite the `Expression`:

```
public class AccountModelRewriter : ExpressionVisitor
{

    private Stack<ParameterExpression[]> _LambdaStack = new Stack<ParameterExpression[]>();

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)node;

        _LambdaStack.Push(
            lambda.Parameters.Select(parameter => typeof(AccountModel) == parameter.Type ? Expression.Parameter(typeof(Account)) : parameter)
            .ToArray()
        );

        lambda = Expression.Lambda(
            this.Visit(lambda.Body),
            _LambdaStack.Pop()
        );

        return lambda;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)node;

        var declaringType = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        if (typeof(AccountModel) == declaringType)
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "Bal" :
                    propertyName = "Balance";
                    break;
                case "Name" :
                    propertyName = "CustomerName";
                    break;
            }

            memberExpression = Expression.Property(
                this.Visit(memberExpression.Expression),
                typeof(Account).GetProperty(propertyName)
            );
        }

        return memberExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        node = (ParameterExpression)base.VisitParameter(node);
        if (typeof(AccountModel) == node.Type)
        {
            node = this._LambdaStack.Peek().Single(parameter => parameter.Type == typeof(Account));
        }
        return node;
    }

}
```

This visitor switches the input parameters from type `AccountModel` to `Account` (that's the `VisitLambda` and `VisitParameter` methods), and also changes all property accessors to use this new parameter as well as switching the property names if appropriate (that's the `VisitMember` part).

Usage is as follows:

```
Expression<Func<AccountModel, bool>> accountModelQuery = a => a.Bal == 0 && a.Name != null && a.Id != 7;

var accountQuery = (Expression<Func<Account, bool>>)new AccountModelRewriter().Visit(accountModelQuery);
```

Comment: What I need is a way to map the `Expression<Func<AccountModel, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Account, bool>>`.

Comment: @ByronSommardahl Oh, sorry. I've revised my answer with a method of doing what you require.

Comment: Should the converted expression work with EntityFramework in a .Where() ext method?

Comment: @ByronSommardahl I don't believe it will work; entity framework does not understand how to compile or use compiled expressions.

Comment: @ByronSommardahl @Lukazoid It's true, the previous example would not have worked with Entity Framework (I didn't realise that was a requirement of the question). However, my edit above uses `ExpressionVisitor` to rewrite the query. If you have a lot of cases such as these which differ slightly then AutoMapper may be the best choice. If this is a one off, or you can't or would prefer not to use a third party library, then my example may be the best way.